# Subgroups under direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K_{1}$ be a normal subgroup of $G_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ be a normal subgroup of $G_{2}$. Show that:
1. $K_{1}\times K_{2}$ is a normal subgroup of $G_{1}\times G_{2}$.
2. $\frac{G_{1}\times G_{2}}{K_{1}\times K_{2}}\cong \frac{G_{1}}{K_{1}}\times \frac{G_{2}}{K_{2}}$.

For the first part I'm stuck at proving $K_{1}\times K_{2}$ is normal. My intuition tells me I should find a homomorphism that maps from something to $G_{1}\times G_{2}$ such that $K_{1}\times K_{2}$ is the kernel. But what is this something and how exactly does this mapping work?

For the second part, I can make sense in my brain that the quotient group of $\frac{G_{1}\times G_{2}}{K_{1}\times K_{2}}$ is homomorphic to $G_{1}\times G_{2}$ and thus should be isomorphic to the direct product of $\frac{G_{1}}{K_{1}}$ and $\frac{G_{2}}{K_{2}}$. But I am somewhat stuck at the exact line of logic to follow in order to produce a sound proof.

Any help is appreciated!

p.s.Thanks for everyone who contributed! I've had a valuable lesson.

Comment: You can just apply the definition of normal subgroup to the subgroup $K_1\times K_2$ in $G_1\times G_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Let $(g_1, g_2)\in G_1\times G_2$. You need to show that

$$(g_1, g_2)K_1\times K_2(g_1, g_2)^{-1} = K_1\times K_2$$

Pick $(k_1, k_2)\in K_1\times K_2$. Then

$$(g_1, g_2)(k_1, k_2)(g_1, g_2)^{-1}=(g_1k_1g_1^{-1}, g_2k_2g_2^{-1})$$

and the right side is in $K_1\times K_2$ because both $K_1, K_2$ are normal subgroups.

So what I've shown is that for any $(g_1, g_2)\in G_1\times G_2$ we have

$$(g_1, g_2)K_1\times K_2(g_1, g_2)^{-1} \subseteq K_1\times K_2$$

It follows from general facts that if "$\subseteq$" holds for **any** $(g_1, g_2)$ then "$=$" holds as well. Do you see how it can be proved?

---

**2)** Define

$$f:(G_1\times G_2)/(K_1\times K_2)\to (G_1/K_1)\times(G_2/K_2)$$
$$f((g_1, g_2)K_1\times K_2) = (g_1K_1, g_2K_2)$$

You need to prove that $f$ is an isomorphism. But first step would be that $f$ is well defined, i.e. that the definition does not depend on the representation of $(g_1, g_2)K_1\times K_2$. So assume that

$$(g_1, g_2)K_1\times K_2 = (h_1, h_2)K_1\times K_2$$

This is if and only if $(g_1h_1^{-1}, g_2h_2^{-1})\in K_1\times K_2$ and thus $g_1h_1^{-1}\in K_1$ and $g_2h_2^{-1}\in K_2$. Therefore $g_1K_1=h_1K_1$ and $g_2K_2=h_2K_2$ so the function is correctly defined.

The only thing left to prove is that $f$ is a homomorphism, "onto" and "1-1". Can you finish the proof?

Comment: For part 1: Yes I do see now! This is precisely the definiton of normal subgroup, that $gxg^{-1}\in X$ For part 2: I'm working on it! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Would you mind giving a little hint about when, in general or in this case, do I need to verify if this $f$ mapping is well-defined? Thanks!

Comment: @AllenAi You always need to verify if $f$ is well defined if the definition may lead to different values. For example if $G$ is a group and $H$ is a (nontrivial) normal subgropu and I define $f: G/H\to G$ as $f(gH) = g$ then this function is not well defined. That's because if I pick 2 different $a, b\in G$ such that $aH=bH$ (such $a, b$ exist since $H$ is nontrivial) then $a = f(aH) = f(bH) = b$ so it's a contradiction. Thus such function cannot exist so it is not well defined.

Comment: @AllenAi So in case of equivalence classes (the case above) you have to ensure that if $f$ maps entire equivalence class **but** is defined by taking an element of that equivalent class **then** it does not depend on the picked element, i.e. no matter what element you pick it will always give the same value.

Comment: I see! The relation that $aH=bH$ marely means the resulting set $aH$ and $bH$ contains the same elements. This notation has been troubling me since my day 1 in group theory. So for the $f(gH)=g$, $a$ and $b$ may be entirely different yet their cosets with $H$ contains the same elements, such $f$ is essentially mapping one element from $\frac{G}{H}$ to the two different elements in $G$ which violates the well-defined-ness of functions. Dang! You just saved me from walking out of this class and still being like a noob! XP

Comment: Huge THAAAAANKS!

Comment: @AllenAi Exactly! Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to prove the first part. Remember a subgroup $N$ is normal if $aN=Na$, so let's use that! let $(g_1,g_2)\in G_1\times G_2$ be given, then we have 
$$(g_1,g_2) N_1\times N_2 = g_1 N_1\times g_2 N_2=N_1 g_1\times N_2 g_2 = N_1\times N_2(g_1,g_2)$$
As $N_i$ is normal in respective group and the product is componentwise done in the direct product of groups. So it is normal.

For the second part, consider the homomorphism 
$$f:G_1\times G_2\to \frac{G_1}{N_1}\times \frac{G_2}{N_2}$$
by 
$$f((g_1,g_2))=(g_1 N_1,g_2 N_2)$$
Now think of the kernel there and the first isomorphism theorem. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Among the many ways there is one which says that $\ker f$ is a normal subgroup, so actually 1. follows from (the proof of) 2.

Comment: It certainly would do that :)

Comment: I see! The very convenient triangular isomorphism theorem. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, despite you not accepting it :P

Comment: My group theory background is a little rusty so I found @freakish 's hint easier to follow as I can go by first claiming $f$ is well-defined, then homomorphism then bijection. Not that yours is anywhere less than good tho!